# Showing NULL on purpose when a NULL joined value is present in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

I have a table with some input values and a table with lookup values like below:

```
select input.value, coalesce(mapping.value, input.value) result from (
    select 'a' union all select 'c'
) input (value) left join (
    select 'a', 'z' union all select 'b', 'y'
) mapping (lookupkey, value) on input.value = mapping.lookupkey
```

which gives:

```
value | result
--------------
a     | z
c     | c
```

i.e. I want to show the original values as well as the mapped value but if there is none then show the original value as the result.

The above works well so far with `coalesce` to determine if there is a mapped value or not. But now if I allow NULL as a valid mapped value, I want to see NULL as the result and not the original value, since it does find the mapped value, only that the mapped value is NULL. The same code above failed to achieve this:

```
select input.value, coalesce(mapping.value, input.value) result from (
    select 'a' union all select 'c'
) input (value) left join (
    select 'a', 'z' union all select 'b', 'y' union all select 'c', null
) mapping (lookupkey, value) on input.value = mapping.lookupkey
```

which gives the same output as above, but what I want is:

```
value | result
--------------
a     | z
c     | NULL
```

Is there an alternative to `coalesce` that can achieve what I want?

Comment: Why don't you use an 'undefined' value to mark that the value was null in the mapping?

Comment: @AndreiXwe I can, but at some point I will have to replace 'undefined' back to null, and in case the original IS 'undefined' I don't want to replace it, so not a silver bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a `case` expression e.g.

```
select input.[value]
  , coalesce(mapping.[value], input.[value]) result
  , case when mapping.lookupkey is not null then mapping.[value] else input.[value] end new_result
from (
    select 'a'
    union all
    select 'c'
) input ([value])
left join (
    select 'a', 'z'
    union all
    select 'b', 'y'
    union all
    select 'c', null
) mapping (lookupkey, [value]) on input.[value] = mapping.lookupkey
```

Returns:

```
value   result  new_result
a       z       z
c       c       NULL
```

Comment: Very nice! Learnt something new today, thank you! Is `CASE` something universal? i.e. ISO standard so that if I need to move to other database provider this still works?

Comment: @user1589188 Don't confuse _standard_ with _portable_. Most databases can handle both `select 30 / 3 / 5;` and `select 30 / -3 / 5;`. SQL Server handles them _differently_. Sites like [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) let you try things out on different databases.